# Official Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen Display not working

Tags: touchscreen, kali

I have bought an "Official Raspberry Pi 7" Touchscreen Display" and a raspberry pi, i have flashed the sd card with Kali Linux, but when i turn the pi on, there is nothing, but a white screen. I have configured it, and it gets detected.

---

I have now switched to Raspberry Pi O/S, and its the same

---

Pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN4D1.jpg

The red is at pin 6 now.

Comment: Try Raspberry Pi OS.

Comment: Any reason to expect it to work?  I believe it's a kernel patch on Raspberry Pi O/S. As Kali is really not an O/S for end users (it's more a toolkit) support is better on the Kali forums - for example https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?42395-Help-installing-Kali-Linux-on-RPI3b&highlight=touch+screen - close vote from me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Kali is not an end user O/S.

Comment: Post a photo showing both ends of the ribbon cable inserted in the Pi and screen circuit board connectors. What power supply are you using?

Comment: 'The red is at pin 6 now.' this is wrong, pin 6 is ground.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Pi end of the cable is inserted fully?

I've used red cable pin2 5V, black cable pin6 Ground.

https://pinout.xyz

[image]

Comment: The Pi end of the cable is inserted fully, i have changed the cables to what you said, but it's the same.

Comment: Maybe you've damaged the screen/board by having the 5V and Gnd the wrong way round. Has this screen ever worked?

Comment: It haven't ever worked, the first time i tried it, it the cables was correct in it, i have just tried different things after that.

Comment: Sounds like you need to return it.